# What is the difference between glTexParameter and glSamplerParameter

Tags: opengl, textures

Because I am no expert, please dont consider this question silly.
I have read several tutorials where texture parameters were set using glTexParameter. I am talking about GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER , GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R etc..
Suddenly I come across a tutorial that now used glSamplerParameter to set these parameters.

I see there are some common parameters between glTexParameter and glSamplerParameter like (GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER , GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_LOD etc), and there are some that are only applicable in glTexParameter (GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_R etc). I perfectly understand the uncommon ones because after all, the  glTexParameter is acting on the image, and these parameters are specifying attributes image per se.

But I dont quite understand why are there some parameters that are common between these 2 GL calls. Which should be used when?  In my opinion sampling parameters like (GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER , GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, etc) should only be applicable to sampler (glSamplerParameter) and not to glTexParameter.

Please help me understand the difference between two.

Answer (score 12):

`glSamplerParameter` is relatively new. The way a texture is sampled is actually a property of the thing doing the sampling, not of the texture itself — not just in semantic terms but on actual, real hardware.

Besides the desire to represent things as they actually function on the hardware, tying two unrelated things together can cost you in performance terms. If you make the way something is sampled a property of the sampler then e.g. you can sample the same texture in two different ways within the same shader. If it's a property of the texture then you're going to have to upload the same texture twice or write a multi-pass shader.

Hence the two things are now being separated.

Comment: it sounds like using glSamplerParameter is better in many ways. Can you point out the cases where usingl glTexParameter has its advantages?

Comment: @kvikram: There really are none =P Sampler objects are the way it should have worked all along, and the way it already worked in D3D for years. Having sampler state separate from texture object is a tremendous boost, you can change filter mode simply by binding a different sampler to a TMU. They are an OpenGL 3.3 feature, but pretty widely supported.

Answer (score 4):

Look here for a [reference about Sampler Objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object)
And [here from geeks3d](http://www.geeks3d.com/20110908/opengl-3-3-sampler-objects-control-your-texture-units/)

It was added to Core OpenGL in version 3.3 (so should be quite well adapted today).

In general it separates sampling from textures from the texture data. Previously it was both task of Texture Object (which was quite inefficient and problematic). Now the new solution gives a lot of flexibility.

Parameters are the same as for texture objects but relates only to sampling: `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S​, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T​, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R​, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER​, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER​, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR​, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_LOD​, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LOD​, GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS​, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE​, or GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC​`